# Real example of Func<sometype> + Func<sometype>

Tags: c#, lambda

Lets say you have:

```
Func<string> a = () => "string here";
Func<string> b = () => "other string here";

var c = a + b;
```

What the realworld need for this?

Comment: None. That does not make any sense at all. It does not even compile. What is your question?

Comment: @Aron: It does compile. What makes you think it shouldn't?

Comment: @Jon: Actually i'm reading your book now, and picked this example from there. Just dont understand how use this?

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy: Ha :) Where does the example come from in the book? Will try to add some more context to the answer

Comment: @Jon: It's a 13.3.5, You're giving the example of how variance works, with Func<string> and Func<object>

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy: Ah, right. Just use the example in that context then - demonstrating what's possible. It doesn't mean it's *useful* :) (There are some very limited uses, as per my answer, but it would be very unusual.) The main thing is to understand how variance works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only time I can think of it being useful is if you're actually going to treat it as a list of delegates (via [`Delegate.GetInvocationList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist)), and invoke each one separately. You could do that for validators, for example - where each validation step could return `null` for "valid" or an error message otherwise. It would be very rare to do so though.

The predominant usage for delegate combination is for event handlers - where usually the delegate type is compatible with `EventHandler` (with a `void` return type). At that point, the behaviour of multi-cast delegates returning the result of the *last* action invoked doesn't matter, as there's no return value anyway.